# solana/sdk/docker-solana/build.sh in solana repository

Tags: solana-cli

What's going on in this sh file and how can I use this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

cd "$(dirname "$0")"/../..
eval "$(ci/channel-info.sh)"
source ci/rust-version.sh

CHANNEL_OR_TAG=
if [[ -n "$CI_TAG" ]]; then
  CHANNEL_OR_TAG=$CI_TAG
else
  CHANNEL_OR_TAG=$CHANNEL
fi

if [[ -z $CHANNEL_OR_TAG ]]; then
  echo Unable to determine channel or tag to publish into, exiting.
  echo "^^^ +++"
  exit 0
fi

cd "$(dirname "$0")"
rm -rf usr/
../../ci/docker-run.sh "$rust_stable_docker_image" \
  scripts/cargo-install-all.sh sdk/docker-solana/usr

cp -f ../../scripts/run.sh usr/bin/solana-run.sh
cp -f ../../fetch-spl.sh usr/bin/
(
  cd usr/bin
  ./fetch-spl.sh
)

docker build -t solanalabs/solana:"$CHANNEL_OR_TAG" .

maybeEcho=
if [[ -z $CI ]]; then
  echo "Not CI, skipping |docker push|"
  maybeEcho="echo"
else
  (
    set +x
    if [[ -n $DOCKER_PASSWORD && -n $DOCKER_USERNAME ]]; then
      echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login --username "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
    fi
  )
fi
$maybeEcho docker push solanalabs/solana:"$CHANNEL_OR_TAG"
```

Source: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/docker-solana/build.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That builds a Solana Docker image and, alternately, pushes it to the Docker public repository. This is run as part of the automated build process by authorized Solana team.

You don't need to run it as you can just pull the published docker image.